# django set boolean field value in views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to set all BooleanField values to False with button in my template.

model:

```
class VyberJedla(models.Model):

    nazov_jedla = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingrediencie = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    vybrane = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazov_jedla
```

view:

```
def vymazatVybrane(request):
    jedlo = VyberJedla.objects.all
    jedlo.vybrane = False
    jedlo.save()

    return redirect('/')
```

template(button):

```
<a href="{% url 'vymazatVybrane' %}">
      <button type="button">
      CHECK
      </button></a>
```

error: 
AttributeError at /vymazatVybrane
'method' object has no attribute 'vybrane'

Comment: `jedlo` is here a queryset (a collection, although not even that since you did not *call* the `.all()` method) of `VyberJedla` objects. Not a single `VyberJadla`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the `vybrane` field of *all* `VyberJedla` records to `False`, you should use [**`.update(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
def vymazatVybrane(request):
    jedlo = VyberJedla.objects.all().update(vybrane=False)
    return redirect('/')
```

If you want to only set a subset of the `VyberJedla` records, you need to [**`.filter(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) the queryset.

Note that usually GET methods are *not* supposed to change entities (and their values). You might consider making this a POST/PATCH request.